# What's a good Java library for dynamic SOAP client operations?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, client

I've been searching for SOAP client libraries for Java and have found a plethora of libraries based on the idea of building stub and proxy classes based on a WSDL.  I'm interested in allowing the user to enter a WSDL at runtime, parsing the WSDL, then allowing the user to perform operations on the Web Service.

Does anyone know of a good SOAP client library which will allow this runtime use? Or is there a way I can use the axis2 wsdl2java functionality to build stubs into the classloader and use them at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Later than never. :)

You should achieve that in two steps:

- 1) parse the WSDL informed by the user to retrieve the available operations. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611034/simple-way-to-parse-a-wsdl) to know how to do this in a simple way.
- 2) Create a dynamic client to send a request using the selected operations. It can be done by using the [Dispatch](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-dispatch-api.html) API from [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/).

Build the `Dispatch` object for the dynamic client (It can be created on the fly by informing web service endpoint, port name, etc):

```
package com.mycompany.demo;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

public class Client {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    QName serviceName = new QName("http://org.apache.cxf", "stockQuoteReporter");
    Service s = Service.create(serviceName);

    QName portName = new QName("http://org.apache.cxf", "stockQuoteReporterPort");
    Dispatch<DOMSource> dispatch = s.createDispatch(portName,
                                                  DOMSource.class,
                                                  Service.Mode.PAYLOAD);
    ...
  }
}
```

Construct the request message (In the example below we are using [DOMSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMSource.html)):

```
// Creating a DOMSource Object for the request
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document requestDoc = db.newDocument();
Element root = requestDoc.createElementNS("http://org.apache.cxf/stockExample", "getStockPrice");
root.setNodeValue("DOW");
DOMSource request = new DOMSource(requestDoc);
```

Invoke the web service

```
// Dispatch disp created previously
DOMSource response = dispatch.invoke(request);
```

Recommendations:

- Use `((BindingProvider)dispatch).getRequestContext().put("thread.local.request.context", "true");` if you want to make the Dispatch object thread safe.
- Cache the `Dispatch` object for using later, if it is the case. The process o building the object is not for free.

**Other Methods**

There are other methods for creating dynamic clients, like using CXF [dynamic-clients](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/dynamic-clients.html) API. You can read in project's index page:

> CXF supports several alternatives to allow an application to
>   communicate with a service without the SEI and data classes

I haven't tried that myself but should worth giving it a try.