# How do I build a Soap (WSDL) reader in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

So I have an WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.webserviceX.NET" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <s:element name="GetWeather">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CityName" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CountryName" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetWeatherResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetWeatherResult" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetCitiesByCountry">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CountryName" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetCitiesByCountryResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetCitiesByCountryResult" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="string" nillable="true" type="s:string" />
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="GetWeatherSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetWeather" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetWeatherSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetWeatherResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCitiesByCountrySoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCitiesByCountry" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCitiesByCountrySoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCitiesByCountryResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetWeatherHttpGetIn">
    <wsdl:part name="CityName" type="s:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="CountryName" type="s:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetWeatherHttpGetOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCitiesByCountryHttpGetIn">
    <wsdl:part name="CountryName" type="s:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCitiesByCountryHttpGetOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetWeatherHttpPostIn">
    <wsdl:part name="CityName" type="s:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="CountryName" type="s:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetWeatherHttpPostOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCitiesByCountryHttpPostIn">
    <wsdl:part name="CountryName" type="s:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCitiesByCountryHttpPostOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="GlobalWeatherSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetWeather">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get weather report for all major cities around the world.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetWeatherSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetWeatherSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCitiesByCountry">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get all major cities by country name(full / part).</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCitiesByCountrySoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCitiesByCountrySoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:portType name="GlobalWeatherHttpGet">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetWeather">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get weather report for all major cities around the world.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetWeatherHttpGetIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetWeatherHttpGetOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCitiesByCountry">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get all major cities by country name(full / part).</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCitiesByCountryHttpGetIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCitiesByCountryHttpGetOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:portType name="GlobalWeatherHttpPost">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetWeather">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get weather report for all major cities around the world.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetWeatherHttpPostIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetWeatherHttpPostOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCitiesByCountry">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get all major cities by country name(full / part).</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCitiesByCountryHttpPostIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCitiesByCountryHttpPostOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="GlobalWeatherSoap" type="tns:GlobalWeatherSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetWeather">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetWeather" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCitiesByCountry">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="GlobalWeatherSoap12" type="tns:GlobalWeatherSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetWeather">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetWeather" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCitiesByCountry">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="GlobalWeatherHttpGet" type="tns:GlobalWeatherHttpGet">
    <http:binding verb="GET" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetWeather">
      <http:operation location="/GetWeather" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <http:urlEncoded />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCitiesByCountry">
      <http:operation location="/GetCitiesByCountry" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <http:urlEncoded />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="GlobalWeatherHttpPost" type="tns:GlobalWeatherHttpPost">
    <http:binding verb="POST" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetWeather">
      <http:operation location="/GetWeather" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCitiesByCountry">
      <http:operation location="/GetCitiesByCountry" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="GlobalWeather">
    <wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherSoap" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherSoap12" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherHttpGet" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherHttpGet">
      <http:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherHttpPost" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherHttpPost">
      <http:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

What I need to do is extract some of the details from the file. Like in this format:

```
**Server Details**
Server = www.webservicex.net
Path = /globalweather.asmx
Port = 80
Action = http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry

**Input XML**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetCitiesByCountry xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
<CountryName>string</CountryName>
</GetCitiesByCountry>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

**Output XML**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetCitiesByCountryResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
<GetCitiesByCountryResult>string</GetCitiesByCountryResult>
</GetCitiesByCountryResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Has anyone got any ideas. I Have been searching for days now without any luck?

Answer (score 0):

You can try wsdlParser

```
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.wsdl.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fwst%2Fwsdl%2Futil%2FWSDLParser.html
```

or wsdlReader

```
http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/apis/wsdl4j/javax/wsdl/xml/WSDLReader.html
```

to write a java code as per your requirement for parsing wsdl. Here are some useful links.

http://www.membrane-soa.org/soa-model-doc/1.2/parse-wsdl-java-api.htm

http://code.google.com/p/wsdl-parser/source/browse/trunk/+wsdl-parser+--username+smartzxy/wsdl-parser/test/org/softTank/wsdlParser/WsdlParserImplTest.java?r=3

[Simple way to parse a WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611034/simple-way-to-parse-a-wsdl)